# How to display individual data on [slug].js page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, next.js

In the components folder I have a "list.js" file in which I edit all data. I imported this into the "Card.js" file and define the styling of the individual cards.
In the Pages folder under stories you will find two more files. One is called "[slug].js" and the other "index.js". In the index.js file I use .map to display the cards and have a redirect for the individual content.

Unfortunately I can't get any further in the "[slug].js" file. If I want to display the data here, the individual data for this page is not shown correctly. It always gets displayed from all objects but not individually. Already tried with .map and props. How can I only show content specific to the specific page?

card.js

```
import React from 'react'

function Card ({id, title, desc, cat}) {
  return (
    <div className='border rounded hover:shadow-xl p-6'>
      <div className=''>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <p>{desc}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Card
```

list.js

```
const Users=[
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Get Your Ticket for DisruptHR",
        slug: "get-your-ticket-for-disrupthr",
        desc: "dummy first",
        body: "bdcbsadkcbsiducbsiudcbsiudcbsiucdbsuibdcsbdciousdbcsoidcubsdiucbsiudcbsiucb",
        image: "",
        icon: "",
        cat: [
            {first: "muffin"},
            {second: "donut"},
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "People Podcast: Psychological Safety",
        slug: "people-podcast.psychological-safety",
        desc: "dummy second",
        body: "cbdscbsidubcisoudbciusdbcuisbcusbcusbcusbdcubscbsucbsucbscbsubcusdbcusbcsbcusbcubc",
        image: "",
        icon: "",
        cat: [
            {first: "muffin"},
            {second: "donut"},
        ],
    },
  ]
  export default Users;
```

[slug].js

```
import Card from '../../components/Card'
import Users from '../../components/list'

const Details = () => {

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Details</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Details
```

index.js

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import React from 'react'
import Card from '../../components/Card'
import Users from '../../components/list'

const stories = () => {
  return (
    <div className='grid grid-rows-4 grid-flow-col gap-4 mx-10'>
        {Users.map((story, index) => {
          return (
            <Link href={'/stories/' + story.slug}>
            <a key={index}><Card id={story.id} title={story.title} desc={story.desc} cat={story.cat} /></a>
            </Link>
          )
        })}

    </div>
  )
}

export default stories
```

the data are just dummy text for now.

Comment: I'm feeling your `[slug].js` is incomplete. It should have server props for data population.

Comment: I thought this is just the case when fetching some data from an API isn't it?

Comment: *If I want to display the data here, the individual data for this page is not shown correctly* I don't see anywhere you try to get data for `[slug].js`. That makes your code confusing though

Comment: correctly, because i removed it cause it didn't work what i've tried before

Comment: using server props it seems pointless to me because I am not requesting some data from an external api point. but what about using a useEffect hook?